# Can I decrease active machine counts of Ubuntu Pro?

Tags: ubuntu-advantage

I'm a free Ubuntu Pro user. I have detached my machine and attached again. The active machines increased to three. But I have two machines attached actually. Can I decrease active machine counts?

Comment: The number of machines should change automatically.  There is a message when you check your account that says "The number of machines with this token that contacted Ubuntu Pro in the last 24 hours (Beta)" at https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard

Answer (score 3):

The Dashboard has a 24-hour window it looks at for number of systems.  As long as a system checked in with a token within the rolling 24-hour window it'll show up in that value there.  That value doesn't currently update in real-time.

Answer (score 1):

You may use 'sudo pro detach' on a given machine to revoke its Ubuntu Pro subscription.

Comment: Welcome to the site cerfs21 and thank you for this answer.